# Порты на роутере

Tags: сеть, router

Задался вопросом, когда мы передает какой-то трафик по адрессу (к примеру, `24.25.16.13:80`), а он уже через NAT/PAT транслируется на какую-то машину в LAN (к примеру, `191.168.1.14:80`), этот порт `80`, что возле публичного `IP`, он так же должен быть `открыт` или это просто данные для протоколов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порт открыт это не действие на роутере или сервере - это возможность подключиться к нему с клиента.

через роутер пакет проходит так:

сначала в цепочку PREROUTING, если в таблице есть проброс, то меняется адрес назначения и отправляется в FORWARD и POSTROUTING.

если форвард разрешен - то порт открыт

Comment: почитал об этом. теперь понятно. спасибо